# How to set Linear Layout Margin Programmatically (Xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout in my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loginForm_LinearLayout" `
    android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_width="220dp" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"> 

         ...some item... 

</LinearLayout>    `
```

But when program run, i have to change Margin top of this `Linear Layout`. How can do that in `xamarin`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent);

 ll.SetMargins (0,0,0,10);
 mainPanel.LayoutParameters = ll
```

OR

```
var mainPanel = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.mainasdf);
var linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent,
                                                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent);
linearLayoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
mainPanel.LayoutParameters = linearLayoutParams
```